# The plugin `kommunicate_flutter` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: android, flutter, kommunicate

I try to upload kommunicate_flutter: ^1.1.3 in my flutter android app becasue I want to add chatbot in my app but I face this problem , can anyone help me please?

The plugin `kommunicate_flutter` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding.
Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:
https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved in the new versions of Kommunicate Flutter.
Upgrade Kommunicate Flutter's version to resolve the issue.

The Latest Version is 1.4.5.
You can check this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/kommunicate_flutter) for release notes & other details.
Thanks